# Adding column in table with the values in another if matched

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

table1

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 |
| A2 | B2 | C2 |
| A3 | B3 | C3 |
| A4 | B4 | C4 |
| A5 | B5 | C5 |
| A6 | B6 | C6 |

table2

| A | D |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | D1 |
| A3 | D3 |
| A5 | D5 |
| A6 | D6 |

I would like to have table 1 updated with a column D which shows the value in column D joining by A. However, Is altering table 1 adding a column D and then merging both tables and update when matched the way to go or is there any better approach?

Comment: You should not redundantly store data. If you want to add the column to table1, you should probably drop table B afterwards. This said, yes, alter the table, then `update table1 set d = (select d from table2 where table2.a = table1.a)`.

Comment: But that would fail if d does not exist in table1 first, am I correct?

Comment: It depends what is the case you working on, would creating simple view of joining these 2 table be sufficient for future uses?

Comment: @jeiv: Yes, if you want an additional column in a table, the first step is to add this column to the table of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just `join` the value in when you need it:

```
select t1.*, t2.d
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.a = t2.a;
```

If that is not sufficient, you can add the column:

```
alter table1 add d <type>;
```

Then you can update it:

```
update table1 t1
    set d = (select t2.d from table2 t2 where t2.a = t1.a)
    where exists (select t2.d from table2 t2 where t2.a = t1.a);
```